# How to disable generation of default image sizes for some custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails, uploads, images

I used custom post type, where 'thumbnail', 'medium' and 'large' sized not required. I need to disable this sizes and create function or plugin, where i can set, which image size is required for each custom post type.

My first step is hooking of get_intermediate_image_sizes function from wp-includes/media.php. I have added this code to functions.php but it not working :(

```
add_filter('get_intermediate_image_sizes', 'get_intermediate_image_sizes_fixed');
function get_intermediate_image_sizes_fixed() {
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
    //$image_sizes = array('thumbnail', 'medium', 'large'); // Standard sizes
    $image_sizes = array();
    if ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) && count( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) )
        $image_sizes = array_merge( $image_sizes, array_keys( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) );
return apply_filters( 'intermediate_image_sizes', $image_sizes );
}
```

**UPD:** Editing this line in media.php is working. Default types after changes not generating.

```
$image_sizes = array('thumbnail', 'medium', 'large');
```

But how to make work my hook?

Comment: would like an answer to this too

Comment: That's not how you use that filter. To clear default sizes you just need to add it with a very low priority and return an empty array. However that won't solve your problem, because that will affect all post types. I don't think there's a way to do what you want in the current WP version. Try requesting WP devs to add the `$attachment_id` argument to the filter inside [this](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L81) function. That way you can check the post type inside your hook

Comment: My step is only experiment but not full solution. 
How i can use filter correctly? P.S. Thank you for link..

Comment: Any changes to WP that makes it possible now?

Comment: No changes. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the only solution you have at the moment is to disable all intermediate image sizes:

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', '__return_empty_array', 99 );
```

And then manually generate them, depending on the post type, by hooking into 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', where you do have access to the attachment id (and therefore to it's parent post):

```
function do_your_stuff( $data, $attachment_id ) {
  // generate intermediate images

  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'do_your_stuff', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: What are the 10 & 2 parameters you pass into the last add_filter?

Comment: @Luke: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: this answer by @scribu saved the day.